# Php remove JSONArray

Tags: php, json

I have a JSONArray like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 64,
    "name": "leroy"
  },
  {
    "id": 82,
    "name": "guillaume"
  }
]
```

Is it possible to return this instead, with PHP?

```
{
  "id": 64,
  "name": "leroy"
},
{
  "id": 82,
  "name": "guillaume"
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The first output is valid JSON, the second one is not.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought this would be valid too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use below code for remove brackets in json

```
str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES));
```